# Understanding first class functions

Tags: python, decorator, wrapper

I am trying to understand first class functions and how they may be used in a practical example. The example that I came up with is for authentication before calling specific functions for a logged-in user. For example:

```
def authenticate(user_id):
    if user_id != 1: return None
    def call_func(func_name):
        print(f"{user_id} is logged in! ==> Calling function '{func_name}'")
    return call_func

user0 = authenticate(user_id=0)
if user0: user0(func_name='xyz')
user1 = authenticate(user_id=1)
if user1: user1(func_name='xyz')
```

Which prints:

> 1 is logged in! ==> Calling function 'xyz'

Is this a proper understanding of first-class functions? The above seems more like the concept of a `wrapper` or `decorator`. Are these basically the same thing, or what's the difference between these three concepts?

Comment: I think there might be a category error here in your understanding. "First-class functions" isn't a technique; it's a description of the fact that functions in the language you're using are first-class. One of the techniques you can use to exploit this fact is wrapping and/or decoration. There are others.

Comment: "first class" just means that the functions are themselves objects that can be passed around, stored in variables etc. Contrast that to C where a function isn't an object. If you want to pass a function, the best you can do is pass a pointer to the function.

Comment: I think this is too broad for Stack Overflow - there are lots of definitions of the concept of "first class functions" you can find online. Decorators is a concept built on that - a decorator is a function whose input and output are both functions, and you can't do that without having first-class functions in the first place. But decorators are only one of several things that is enabled by having first-class functions.

Comment: The concept that you're thinking of involving passing functions around is called "higher order functions".

Answer (score 2):

First class simply means it can exist on its own. It is not required to be accompanied by no one.

### Methods

Where in languages like Java and C#, you create classes to shove *methods* into.

```java
class Logger {
    public Logger(string name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public void Log(string msg) {
        System.out.print(name + msg);
    }
}
```

And then you use instances of those classes to call the methods.

```java
Logger logger = new Logger("a name");
logger.Log("a message");
```

*A function can only exist as a method of a class. The class is the first class citizen.*

### Functions

In languages like python you can just have a function.

```py
def log(name, msg):
    print(name, msg)
```

And just call that function.

```py
log('a name', 'a message')
```

*A function can simply exist.*

### Notes on Python

Python has classes has well. So if you still want to avoid typing `'a name'` all the time, you can use them.

```py
class Logger:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def log(self, msg):
        print(self.name, msg)

logger = Logger('a name')
logger.log('a message')
```

And since functions are *first class citizens*, closures are a thing as well and the same can be achieved, again, with just functions.

```py
def logger(name):
    def log(msg):
        print(name, msg)
    return log

log = logger('a name')
log('a message')
```

#### Decorators

Decorators are simply functions that make use other function.Take the previous `log` function for example. If we have a `fuzz` decorator, and decorate the `log` function with it, it essentially replaces our log function by its own (that happens to call ours).

```py
def fuzz(func):
    def fuzzed_func(*args, **kwargs):
        print('fuzz')
        func(*args, **kwargs)
        print('fuzz')
    return fuzzed_func

@fuzz
def log(name, msg):
    print(name, msg)
```

> fuzz
>
> a name a message
>
> fuzz

---

*Note 1. data types are first class citizens as well, in all example given here. The `string` is by itself in Java. As `'a name'` is a `str` by itself, as well, in Python. So, not only functions and classes apply to the first class.*

*Note 2. Also consider in the case of a class, you can have methods that do not act on `self` or `this`, they are referenced as static methods. Essentially a function in a class.*

### Extras

There is a fantastic satire about exactly this, you may want to read at some point.

[Execution in the Kingdom of Nouns by Steve Yegge](http://steve-yegge.blogspot.com/2006/03/execution-in-kingdom-of-nouns.html)

David Beazley, just recently at PyCon 2019, gave an outstanding talk, loosely on this topic, that demonstrates quite brilliantly the power of a function.

[Lambda Calculus from the Ground Up](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pkCLMl0e_0k)